# Django Multiple File Field

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models

Is there a model field that can handle multiple files or multiple images for django?  Or is it better to make a ManyToManyField to a separate model containing Images or Files?

I need a solution complete with upload interface in django-admin.

Comment: Model fields are not used for upload. Are you looking to store these files/images in the database or to upload them via your browser?

Comment: store them in the database, basically the same as a single file field but be able to iterate over them

Answer (score 14):

For guys from 2017 and later, there is a [special section in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files). My personal solution was this (successfully works in admin):

```
class ProductImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # this will return only first saved image on save()
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ['image', 'position']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # multiple file upload
        # NB: does not respect 'commit' kwarg
        file_list = natsorted(self.files.getlist('{}-image'.format(self.prefix)), key=lambda file: file.name)

        self.instance.image = file_list[0]
        for file in file_list[1:]:
            ProductImage.objects.create(
                product=self.cleaned_data['product'],
                image=file,
                position=self.cleaned_data['position'],
            )

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Where this natsorted came from?

Comment: Found, im using your sollution, but im getting empty list on file_list, you overrided your html or something?

Comment: Pls set a breakpoint at that line and inspect what's inside `self.files`. Things change, I only gave an idea and you must test and understand what's going on.

Comment: the self.files changed... i check to get getlist('images') instead

Comment: You'll want to use the same form field name as the field in your model, so don't call the form field `files` if your model has a field called `file`. The suffix in `{}-image` also needs to match your field name. You may want to use the `ClearableFileInput` widget or, if in admin, use `admin.widgets.AdminFileWidget`.

Answer (score 7):

No there isn't a single field that knows how to store multiple images shipped with Django. Uploaded files are stored as file path strings in the model, so it's essentially a `CharField` that knows how to be converted to python.

The typical multiple image relationship is built as a separate Image model with an FK pointing to its relevant model, such as `ProductImage -> Product`.

This setup makes it very easy to add into the django admin as an `Inline`.

An M2M field would make sense if you it's truly a many to many relationship where say `GalleryImages` are referenced from 1 or more `Gallery` objects.

Answer (score 5):

I had to change from having a single file to multiple files in an existing system and after a bit of research ended up using this: https://github.com/bartTC/django-attachments

It should be easy to subclass the model if you want custom methods.

Answer (score 2):

**FilerFileField and FilerImageField in one model:**

They are subclasses of django.db.models.ForeignKey, so the same rules apply. The only difference is, that there is no need to declare what model we are referencing (it is always filer.models.File for the FilerFileField and filer.models.Image for the FilerImageField).

**Simple example models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField
from filer.fields.file import FilerFileField

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    disclaimer = FilerFileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**Multiple image file fields on the same model in models.py:**

*Note: related_name attribute required, it is just like defining a foreign key relationship.*

```
from django.db import models
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover = FilerImageField(related_name="book_covers")
    back = FilerImageField(related_name="book_backs")
```

This answer code taken from [django-filer document](http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#filerfilefield-and-filerimagefield)

Comment: I'm afraid you answered a question opposite to the one being asked.  "single field but able to iterate over them", a one to many relationship.  What you mention is a many to one solution.

Comment: It's absolutely not what Dave've been asking for! He asked about upload multiple files at ounce in django admin (for example, when you want to upload 100 images to album)